# rails: render variable with layout doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, renderpartial

I have the following two lines in my rails 3.2 application. The first one works, the second doesn't - the layout is not applied.

```
<%= render partial: 'question_pages/question_page', layout: 'layouts/question_page', locals: {question_page: question_page} %>

<%= render question_page, layout: 'layouts/question_page' %>
```

Any ideas on why I can't pass layout to `render variable`?

Comment: What exactly is the value of `question_page`? Is it a symbol? A string? Something else?

Comment: It's an ActiveRecord object of type QuestionPage. Thus when calling `render question_page`, rails will look for a partial view named question_pages/_question_page.html.erb and pass the object as "question_page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited because of new answer:**
I patched Rails because I thought this wasn't possible, but the Rails devs told me better:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7169

You can specify a layout by calling `render partial: @variable, layout: 'somelayout'`. Whenever you include extra options, you have to specify `partial:`.